# Remote Objects do not work when rendered as PDF?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, pdf, remote-objects, renderas

I want to use Visualforce remote object to retrieve data and display it as PDF.

I use this code.

```
<apex:remoteObjects jsNamespace="RemoteObjectModel">
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Opportunity" 
                     fields="Id,Name,StageName" jsShorthand="opp">
        <apex:remoteObjectField name="Sent__c" jsShorthand="sent"/>
    </apex:remoteObjectModel>
</apex:remoteObjects>

<script>
    function retrieveOpp(){
        var record = new RemoteObjectModel.opp();
        record.retrieve({limit:1}, function(err, records, event){
                console.log(err,records,event);
            });
        }
        window.onload = retrieveOpp();
</script>
```

When VF page is set to `renderAs="PDF"` then console display nothing. When I remove the `renderAs` tag then console displays the retrieved result.

Is this standard behavior and documented?

Comment: Depending on your requirements you can take a look at the pilot feature for advanced pdf rendering. That does support javascript: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_vf_advanced_pdf.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm):

> PDF rendering doesn’t support JavaScript-rendered content.